# GRUB Screen disappeared

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, display, boot-repair

I have a dual boot Windows/Ubuntu laptop and I recently upgraded to Windows 10 (might be relevant). After a month or so, the GRUB menu stopped appearing out of the blue. Despite running boot-repair several times and modifying `/etc/default/grub` , I can't get the GRUB menu to show up or even enter the BIOS.

Output from the last time I ran boot-repair:-
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12796271/

I noticed in the output that there is only one device with a mount point. Is that the problem? How do I fix it?

**EDIT 1:**

I tried the left shift key & grub-install, but that didn't work.
There is also a problem in the partition table.
Output of

```
df -h
```

is:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7        89G   80G  4.1G  96% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           386M  1.2M  385M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G   13M  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Earlier, in place of partitions named "none", there used to be Windows partitions (bootloader (/dev/sda1), C drive (/dev/sda2) & F drive (/dev/sda5)

[Output of sudo fdisk -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZHNN.png)

**EDIT 2:**

I added the following line to /etc/default/grub:-

```
GRUB_INIT_TUNE = "480 440 1"
```

Now, I get a beep on startup indicating grub has started but a black screen on the monitor instead of the grub menu. How should this be fixed?

**EDIT 3:**

It looks like the GRUB menu works but doesn't show up on the screen. So, I took my chances and tried to enter Windows after the BEEP (mentioned in Edit 2) by going to the appropriate GRUB entry number (later tried with `sudo grub-reboot` . After selecting Windows, a backlit screen appears (same as the GRUB menu) and the Windows login sound can be heard. However, **nothing shows up on the screen** even after leaving it for about an hour. Why is Windows not showing up?

**EDIT 4:**

So, I found out that my Windows & GRUB screen are actually there, they just don't show up on my laptop screen. However, on connecting an external screen, I could see the GRUB screen and could also use Windows. How should I solve this one?

Comment: Your Boot Repair output shows a `grub.cfg` file with a Windows entry, so you *should* be seeing a GRUB entry. I suspect a problem with the GRUB timeout. The various entries relating to the timeout look OK to me, but I've long since given up trying to parse GRUB's configuration file. Perhaps [GRUB Customizer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134) will help.

Answer (score 1):

Start the computer and hold down the

```
Left shift key
```

while booting, which should give you the option to choose between Windows and Ubuntu. Choose Ubuntu.

According to your output grub is installed on /dev/sda.
In a terminal type

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

this will reinstall grub and should recreate the grub config correctly.
Reboot and test.

Comment: Please refer to EDIT 1.

Comment: So when you tried left shift key you got no grub menu?

Comment: No. grub-install,  boot-repair, shift key didn't work. Also, there seems to be some problem with the partitions. df -h used to show Windows partitions earlier, but now it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the upgrade to Windows 10 trashed your previously grub-based MBR.  The suggested use of grub-install from Captain should have worked.

The only reason I could think of that it wouldn't would be that your BIOS could actually be booting off of the /dev/sdb device that I saw in your fdisk output.  In that case, you could try running:

> sudo grub-install /dev/sdb

That will install the grub MBR on the other physical disk in your system.

Comment: /dev/sdb1 is my external hard drive.. should i install grub on it? Also if Windows 10 trashed the grub MBR, how am I able to boot into Ubuntu only & not Windows?

Comment: If that's an external device, then I would not install grub on it.

Ah, I wasn't aware that you were able to boot into Ubuntu.  I assumed after upgrading Windows that you were able to boot to that and not Ubuntu.

If that's the case, then clearly grub is still working, but it's probably configured to not show you a boot menu.  You'll want to check the GRUB_TIMEOUT value in /etc/default/grub, and set it to something reasonable (like "10" maybe), and then run update-grub to regenerate the grub configuration file.

Comment: I've tried all possible changes to /etc/default/grub. Still doesn't work. How do I get back the Windows partitions? (Please read EDIT 1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm only new but almost every ossue I ran into with the grub screen was troubleshot booting from a live disc. Could help?

Comment: I tried that too. I booted from a live USB, ran boot-repair. Unfortunately, didn't help.